# How to create random pairs from list

Tags: python, list, random

I am trying to create 8 random pairs from a list of from given 10 images.

```
import random 
imageList = ['1.jpg','2.jpg','3.jpg','4.jpg','5.jpg','6.jpg','7.jpg','8.jpg','9.jpg','10.jpg']

for i in range(len(imageList)):
    imagepair = range(len(imageList) - 1)
```

Comment: Please clarify your question and give some examples, the question as it it posted now it's very unclear

Comment: You might want to tighten up your requirement. Do the random pairs have to be unique within the selected set (8 unique pairs for your example)? Does order matter, e.g is `('1.jpg','2.jpg')` the same as `('2.jpg','1.jpg')`? Can the same image be paired with itself, e.g. `('1.jpg','1.jpg')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `random.shuffle` and create a generator to get samples of image groups as many times as needed.

```
def image_generator(l):
    while True:
        random.shuffle(l)
        yield l[:2]
        
for i in range(8):
    print(next(image_generator(imageList)))
```

```
['6.jpg', '2.jpg']
['10.jpg', '5.jpg']
['8.jpg', '6.jpg']
['6.jpg', '1.jpg']
['5.jpg', '3.jpg']
['8.jpg', '6.jpg']
['6.jpg', '2.jpg']
['8.jpg', '2.jpg']
```

---

Another way is you can use `itertools.product` to get permutations of n (or 2) for images, filtering out cases where both images are the same. And then you can use `random.sample` to get 8 samples.

```
import random
import itertools

def image_generator(iterable, groups, samplesize):
    grouped = (i for i in itertools.product(imageList,repeat=2) if i[0]!=i[1])
    return random.sample(list(grouped), samplesize)

image_generator(imageList, 2, 8)
```

```
[('8.jpg', '7.jpg'),
 ('7.jpg', '10.jpg'),
 ('7.jpg', '2.jpg'),
 ('6.jpg', '7.jpg'),
 ('5.jpg', '3.jpg'),
 ('2.jpg', '1.jpg'),
 ('10.jpg', '5.jpg'),
 ('9.jpg', '10.jpg')]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply shuffle the list, then take the first 4 items from it, and repeat once more:

```
for _ in range(2):
    random.shuffle(imageList)
    i=0
    while(i<8):
        print(imageList[i], imageList[i+1])
        i+=2
```

Answer (score 0):

use random function to get 2 integers as index values and pair the corresponding image.